# Recommend non GPL XMPP server in java

Tags: java, xmpp

It seems nearly all the XMPP java servers such as OpenFire, Tigrese are GPL.

Comment: Is the question you hope to receive an answer on in the title or is this just a statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache vysper is a XMPP server and of course its Apache Licensed.

Answer (score 3):

[Open IM](http://www.openim.techlab.smk.fr/en/) is the only one I could find that isn't GPLed - it's BSDed.